# Bash readin list of files oputput contents of files to one file

Tags: find

Using the `find` command to search for all program files with certain extensions and appending contents to large "codebase.txt" works fine.
Problem is, there are so many versions of the same program (and I want only one unique copy of each progam).
Parsed the list from find command, removing .v1, .v2. .v3, etc of the same program so I have a nice tight clean list of about 300 (pretty much unique file names), down from over 1,000.
Using the various cat commands of reading in filelist to output to "sourcecode.txt" results in errors such as `"invalid use of 'r'"` and I didn't even use the `r` switch.

I know this is easy in bash on Redhat Enterprise Server 7,  but everything I've tried has failed.

I think this is what I'm looking for, but returns an error saying input not recognized.

```
#!/bin/bash                                 
input="filelist.txt"                                  
while IFS= read -r line                                       
do                                                     
  echo "$line".  #append to codebase.txt???? - but how????                   
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Why don't you just `cat filelist.txt >> codebase.txt`? Anyway, the question might benefit from focusing on the point where you are stuck, and a description of the next step you want to take. Please also include a small sample of the input file.

Comment: If you are seeing `invalid option` for options that you don't believe that you are supplying to a command, that's usually an indication that you are passing a filename that begins with a hyphen character

Comment: Apologize for lack of  detail  - typed a much more detailed explanation Wed night at 7:30, with meticulous copies of error messages, submissions, I <KNOW> I clicked "submit", but apparently I did not.  Had to re-create it all from memory Thanksgiving morning.  Web page history was still there this morning, leaving out the much longer explanation, just the attempts:

Comment: I have tried:                                                              
"cat $(grep -v '^#' filelist.txt) > codebase.txt                                      
cat $(filelist.txt) > codebase.txt                                 
sed '/^$/d;/^#/d;s/^/cat "/;s/$/";/' filelist.log | sh > codebase.txt             
with no result, usually an error like "cat: invalid option --'r'                                   Did not even use an 'r' as a switch anywhere!!!! "     - end of tale of woe

Comment: Again, what did NOT work

Comment: cat $(grep -v '^#' filelist.txt) > codebase.txt

Comment: cat $(filelist.txt) > codebase.txt

Comment: sed '/^$/d;/^#/d;s/^/cat "/;s/$/";/' filelist.log | sh > codebase.txt

Comment: cat filelist.txt >> codebase.txt,             copies the list of the filelist.txt to the second file "codebase.txt"

Comment: I was looking for appending the actual contents of each file in filelist.txt to another file "codebase.txt"